# R: Duplicating a subset of row values, based on condition, across a whole dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` containing count data at different sites, across two days:

```
day   site   count
1     A      2
1     B      3
2     A      10
2     B      12
```

I would like to add a new column `day1count` that represents the `count` value at day 1, for each unique site. So, on rows where `day==1`, `count` and `day1count` would be identical. The new `df` would look like:

```
day   site   count   day1count
1     A      2       2
1     B      3       3
2     A      10      2
2     B      12      3
```

So far I've created a new column that has duplicate values for day 1 rows, and NA for everything else:

```
df$day1count= ifelse(df$day==1, df$count, NA)

day   site   count   day1count
1     A      2       2
1     B      3       3
2     A      10      NA
2     B      12      NA
```

How can I now replace the NA entries with values corresponding to each unique site from day 1?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's not very elegant (and I invite others to submit a more efficient approach) but...

Do NOT create the new column with `df$day1count= ifelse(df$day==1, df$count, NA)` as I did in the original example. Instead, start by making a duplicate of `df`, but which only contains rows from day 1

```
tmpdf = df[df$day==1,]
```

Rename `count` as `day1count`, and remove `day` column

```
tmpdf = rename(tmpdf, c("count"="day1count"))
tmpdf$day = NULL
```

Merge the two dataframes by site

```
newdf = merge(x=df,y=tmpdf, by="site")
newdf

  site day count day1count
1    A   1     2         2
2    A   2    10         2
3    B   1     3         3
4    B   2    12         3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(day1count = first(count))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   site [2]
    day site  count day1count
  <int> <fct> <int>     <int>
1     1 A         2         2
2     1 B         3         3
3     2 A        10         2
4     2 B        12         3
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(
  text =
    "day   site   count
1     A      2
1     B      3
2     A      10
2     B      12", header = T
)
```